DuckDB: how do I use the result of a query on `DESCRIBE` to `SELECT` from a table?
Suppose I want to select all columns of a certain type from a DuckDB table. For example, selecting all VARCHAR type columns, after creating a table like:
CREATE TABLE dummy (x VARCHAR, y BIGINT, z VARCHAR);
INSERT INTO dummy
VALUES ('a', 0, 'a'),
  ('b', 1, 'b'),
  ('c', 2, 'c');

Inngeneral, I might have an arbitrary number of VARCHAR type columns, so this query should be "dynamic". I get a list of the relevant columns using DESCRIBE:
SELECT column_name
FROM (DESCRIBE dummy)
WHERE column_type = 'VARCHAR';

This statement gives me a list of the column names which have type VARCHAR. But how do I use this? I tried using the COLUMNS expression:
SELECT COLUMNS(
    c->c IN (
      SELECT column_name
      FROM (DESCRIBE dummy)
      WHERE column_type = 'VARCHAR'
    )
  )
FROM dummy

But this gives me the error: BinderException: Binder Error: Table function cannot contain subqueries. I don't really understand the error. I get the same error when trying:
SELECT COLUMNS(
    c->list_contains(
      (
        SELECT column_name
        FROM (DESCRIBE dummy)
        WHERE column_type = 'VARCHAR'
      ),
      c
    )
  )
FROM dummy

How do I connect the dots between getting a list of columns by querying DESCRIBE tbl, and then using that list to select from tbl?

Try to use the duckdb_columns() function since it provides metadata about the columns available in the DuckDB instance.

SQL-level variables were added in DuckDB 1.1.0
e.g. SET VARIABLE / GETVARIABLE
duckdb.sql("""
SET VARIABLE VARCHAR_NAMES = (
   SELECT LIST(column_name)
   FROM (DESCRIBE dummy)
   WHERE column_type = 'VARCHAR'
)
""")

duckdb.sql("""
FROM DUMMY SELECT COLUMNS(x -> x in GETVARIABLE('VARCHAR_NAMES'))
""")

┌─────────┬─────────┐
│    x    │    z    │
│ varchar │ varchar │
├─────────┼─────────┤
│ a       │ a       │
│ b       │ b       │
│ c       │ c       │
└─────────┴─────────┘


Try to use the duckdb_columns() function since it provides metadata about the columns available in the DuckDB instance :
SELECT column_name
    FROM duckdb_columns()
    WHERE table_name = 'dummy' AND data_type = 'VARCHAR'


I am using Python to concatenate the column names into a single string, then used that string in the SELECT :
import duckdb

con = duckdb.connect('your_database.db')

column_names = con.execute("""
    SELECT column_name
    FROM duckdb_columns()
    WHERE table_name = 'dummy' AND data_type = 'VARCHAR';
""").fetchall()

column_names = [col[0] for col in column_names]

columns_string = ', '.join(column_names)
query = f"SELECT {columns_string} FROM dummy;"

result = con.execute(query).fetchdf()

print(result)

Check @jqurious it may suits you well using SQL level variables.

That only gives me the column names though? I've discovered a few ways to get the column names (and now can add to it the one you shared, thank you), but I do not yet know how to use the column names in order to select from a table with said columns.

Do you mean that you want to retrieve data  from the returned list of the columns ?

yes, that's what I am trying to do, and that's why I get the errors I described above.

As you noticed, the DuckDB binder error message says:

Table function cannot contain subqueries

Effectively, this means that DuckDB does not support the type of "dynamic" SQL you have in mind.
The COLUMNS clause does allow lambdas, which give some degree of flexibility based on the column names, but in general(*), if you want to construct an SQL query dynamically, you have either to use the DuckDB CLI or rely on a programming language (such as Python).
To use the DuckDB CLI, you typically use .once (to write out the constructed query) and then .read (to execute it), as illustrated at https://duckdbsnippets.com/snippets/14/dynamic-sql-in-duckdb-cli

(*) The JSON extension provides some support for executing SQL SELECT statements constructed from JSON.  See json_execute_serialized_sql in the manual.
